# Check url is a file or directory

Tags: python, url

**Hi there.**

I have a URL list. I do not know how to check is this address to a file or directory.

examples:

```
url = "http://example.com/path/to/file.html"

if '.' in url.split('/')[-1]:
    return True
```

but if url is

```
url = "http://example.com/path/domains/domain.com"
```

domain.com is a directory not a file. How to detect it?

Checking the file extension is not good, maybe some headers? But I want to do as little as possible internet transfer usage.

Edit:

I need to download a large number of links and map their path to the location in my operating system. eg 
example.com/path/to/file.html

~/Downloads/example.com/path/to/

and here download file.html.
eg:

```
example.com/directory/  
create ~/Downlods/example.com/directory/ 
next url: example.com/directory/dir2  
create ~/Downloads/example.com/directory/dir2  
next url: example.com/directory/file.html  
Download file.html in too ~/Downloads/example.com/directory/
not too create file.html directory
```

Comment: Really, you can't unless it has a slash at the end.

Comment: all page is in one site? check somethings unique in directory page and crawl pages, and now you can check... but i think best way add extension

Comment: @TylerCrompton Even then it's not a sure-fire thing. A URL is something the server handles, and while some servers map URLs to their filesystem, it's becoming increasingly common not to (mod_rewrite and pals make it very easy not to). You can make any URL point to anything you want on your server.

Comment: @Lattyware, trust me, I know. Though not always, rewrites usually go from a file to a file or from a directory to a directory.

Answer (score 3):

In short, you can't. Accessing the URL http://example.com/path/domains/domain.com would send a 302 redirect (if I remember correctly) to http://example.com/path/domains/domain.com/ by default. There are no headers in the response that indicates if a URL points to a directory. May I ask why you need to know this? I suppose you can add a slash to a URL and see what happens from there. That might get you the results you are looking for.

Comment: Unless it's not backed by the filesystem at all. In which case this whole exercise is pointless.

Comment: Exactly. I'll go so far to say that it's pointless either way.

Comment: I need to download a large number of links and map their path to the location in my operating system

Comment: Look into `wget`. That can download recursively and it creates a file structure on your OS based on the URLs. `curl` may also do it but I don't use it that often.

Comment: @TylerCrompton i know this post is old but the salsh idea was perfect. fixed my problem. thanks

Answer (score 0):

On HTTP servers, there is no such "file" or "directory" things. You just send an URI to the server which identify a specific resource that depends of the server's configuration.
By default, most of the HTTP servers use the files and directories of your system, but it can be configured (URL Rewriting, ...).